# Stopping excel to ask for enabling macros

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

When I open my regular xls file, Excel asks me

> This workbook contains macros. Do you want to disable macros before
>   opening the file?

However, if I open Visual Basic Editor (<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>) there are no Modules listed and I am not aware of any macros used, the most complicated things are some matrix formulas.

---

**Edit:** The problem only occurs if I save in xls. If I change as xlsx (which sadly is not a solution for me) Excel does not ask.

**Edit 2:** The problem occurs as soon as I try to copy a sheet to another file and save. Even if I remove that sheet later, excel keeps asking me about enabling macros. Here is a [test file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14388222/SOexample.xls) for reproduction.

Comment: There can be codes in the worksheet code and ThisWorkbook code.

Comment: See this article: http://www.contextures.com/xlfaqMac.html#NoMacros

Comment: I followed the link and removed everything in the code window (even that the field already seemed blank) for all objects - did not help

Answer (score 1):

If you go into Excel's options (File tab, Options), you'll see a section called Trust Center.

In there, you can add trusted locations and trusted documents. If you apply those to your case, Excel won't give security notifications for your document.

Comment: And just for the record, ["non civil" way to do that](http://superuser.com/a/692486/164837)

Comment: The OP doesn't have any macros (at least that he knows of) so not really the answer to the question which is why is the message appearing.

Comment: The workbook is used as template for a bigger process at which end it gets send to multiple recipients. So this does not really help me.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it happens even if there are no macros..try removing any module present in vba window,and save it.it will resolve the issue.

Comment: If you check the file you will see, that there are no modules